# Why are Python builds suddenly not Framework builds when using virtualenv?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, virtualenv

I've installed Python 2.7 as a Framework build on my Mac. I've installed and confirmed that wxPython works with this Python build. But when I create a virtual environment with virtualenv, the resulting Python executable isn't a Framework build, or at least not according to wxPython:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to add the following script to /Path/To/VirtualEnv/bin:

```
ENV=`python -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"`
PYTHON=`python -c "import sys; print sys.real_prefix"`/bin/python
export PYTHONHOME=$ENV
exec $PYTHON "$@"
```

Then, whenever you want to run GUI (ex wxPython) use `my_script main.py` (make sure that virtualenv is *active*)

Comment: This was easy and works well. I'm running Mavericks 10.9.2. I used it in combination with the info on this site: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, `pythonw` is not available as a Framework. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/gldnspud/virtualenv-pythonw-osx/) available. We're using it like this to make `pythonw` available as a Framework app bundle:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gldnspud/virtualenv-pythonw-osx/master/install_pythonw.py
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gldnspud/virtualenv-pythonw-osx/master/pythonw.c
python install_pythonw.py `which python`/../..
rm install_pythonw.py pythonw.c
```

Answer (score 3):

On 10.10.3, using a virtualenv (via pyenv if it matters), I did a `brew install wxmac`.

I have this atop of my application script

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

And I use this wrapper to run my script, called 'app.py'

```
#!/bin/bash

# what real Python executable to use
PYVER=2.7
PYTHON=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/$PYVER/bin/python$PYVER

# pythonw is key here!
PYTHON="pythonw"

# now run Python with the virtualenv set as Python's HOME
export PYTHONHOME=$VIRTUAL_ENV
exec $PYTHON "$@"
```

Run it with `fwpy app.py`

Answer (score 2):

add

```
export PYTHONHOME=$VIRTUAL_ENV
alias python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3  # set path to ur python
```

in the end of venv **activate** script

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as asked: the Python executable in the virtualenv is a stub that executes the main Python executable, and is not present at a path where a bundle can be automatically recognized.  This results in `Foundation.NSBundle.mainBundle()` returning an `NSBundle` just pointing at the `bin/` directory in the virtualenv, with no associated `Info.plist` and therefore no associated `bundleIdentifier`; this makes it impossible to use certain APIs (such as, as you've noticed, the Cocoa GUI APIs).

I packaged up these workarounds into a small tool you can `pip install` into your virtualenv and then run:

- https://github.com/glyph/venvdotapp/

It's pretty primitive right now; you have to just do `pip install venvdotapp; venvdotapp` in your virtualenv.  You can also do `import venvdotapp; venvdotapp.require_bundle()` if you're writing some code that reqiures your venv have a bundle.