# wxPython in virtualenv on OS X?

Tags: python, wxpython, virtualenv, wxwidgets

I just made a virtualenv, installed py2app and wx, and ran a wxPython app. I got:

```
  class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

For some reason, it never works when it's running from a virtualenv. I've heard this can be fixed by compiling the `wx` python module from source, but I don't have access to any compilers. Is there a way this can be fixed without root, or anything that needs root to install?

I'm using a virtualenv because 2.7 doesn't have py2app on my system, and my admin refuses to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've documented how I use wxPython in a virtualenv on Mac.  It's a bit of a kludge, but it works.  See http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac

Comment: Symlinking wxPython is also how I use it, however I use a script for fixing the Framework problem. No separate command required for running wxPython. See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13289195/58107).

Comment: @RobinDunn - what if there is nothing in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions ?!   This is what I face.  In your instructions, you haven't mentioned how/when you installed wxpython - I wonder if this is the problem.   I have wxpython installed, it works on the native python (/usr/bin/python) but I have no wxredirect.pth on my disk at all!