# Wx can't run on mac

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, anaconda

I installed anaconda instead of system's python on mac,but when I type

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
```

I got this:

> This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a Framework
>   build of python, and only when you are logged in on the main display
>   of your Mac.

I use the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249880/why-are-python-builds-suddenly-not-framework-builds-when-using-virtualenv):

```
#!/bin/bash

# what real Python executable to use
PYVER=2.7
PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/$PYVER/bin/python$PYVER

# find the root of the virtualenv, it should be the parent of the dir this script is in
ENV=`$PYTHON -c "import os; print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(\"$0\"), '..'))"`

# now run Python with the virtualenv set as Python's HOME
export PYTHONHOME=$ENV 
exec $PYTHON "$@"
```

but it just used the system python.Can't use the lib in anaconda.
I want to use the wx GUI in anaconda,how to solve the problem?

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at anaconda.  Does it have a `Python.framework` in its installation?  What about a `pythonw`?

Comment: There is no Python.framework or pythonw in anaconda.

Comment: If you use `conda` to install `python.app` then that will give you a `{prefix}/bin/pythonw` script that will run the framework version of Python.  You can also use `conda` to install wxPython.

Comment: I have installed wxpython,but it's same as before.

Comment: Still using your script above or something like it, or just running anaconda's `pythonw`?  Once I installed the `python.app` and `wxpython` into anaconda then the latter worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue for my Python 2 and 3 virtual envs by reading this post (see my tip in the followed):

- https://blurringexistence.net/wxpython-using-virtualenvwrapper-on-osx.html

My environment is:

- macOS 10.12.5
- Python 2 installed by Homebrew

  - wxPython installed through: brew insstall wxpython
- Python 3 installed by Homebrew

  - wxPython installed through: gpip3 install wxpython (the global PIP for Python 3)

Tips:

- You could modify the script in that post to work for Python 3.
- You should set "PYTHONHOME" in the "activate" file instead of "postactivate" if you DO NOT use virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Tips on link work well. I had wx installed within my virtualenv, instead of globally. Even better for me since I just had to do some of the instructions instead of the whole thing.